# Variable.match for amount > 999.99

Tags: javascript

For example :

```
Var1 = 289.56
```

I use this formula :

```
foundStr = Var1.match("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+");
Price( parseFloat(foundStr).toFixed(2) );
```

But when `Var1 > 999.99` (Example : 2,356.21)

What is the script find the string ?

```
foundStr = Var1.match(??);
```

Thank you

Comment: why are you trying to match a number to a string and then immediately parsing it back to a float?

Comment: I'm written Widget program with javascript :

Comment: function getPrice()
 {
  var url = new URL();
  url.location = "http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/";
  url.fetchAsync(PriceReturn);

  }

function PriceReturn(url)
  { 
   var resultStr = url.result; 
   var subCheck = resultStr.substring(resultStr.indexOf("SILVER"));
   
   foundStr = subCheck.match("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+");
   setOilPrice(parseFloat(foundStr).toFixed(2));
  }

Comment: we know silver amount just 2 digit with 2 decimal, but when I want to check Gold amount is 4 digit with 2 decimal (let say 1,585.23)

Comment: ok so `Var1 = 289.56` (from your original question) isn't really accurate to your situation at all. You really have something like `Var1 = "Some big string with mystery content. Maybe there's a number like 289.56, but I can't be sure";` and you want to see if you can find a number in there?

Comment: Could you please go back and edit your question and add this information? Its really hard to read in the comments. Please adjust your post to show the full problem you have.

Comment: yes, the var1 is changing period, so I can get the price for 2-3digit with 2 decimal with this formula  "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", but when the price is like 1,585.23 what is the formula ?

Answer (score 3):

You already have a numeric variable, why are you messing with strings?

```
var number1 = 289.56;

if (number1 > 999.99) {
    // do whatever
}
```

If you're trying to round, use Math.floor instead:

```
var number1 = 289.56485345734593453;
var roundedNumber1 = Math.floor(number1 * 10) / 10; // two decimal points
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to remove the commas and check if its a float, but its hard to tell based off your question. How about something like this:

```
var Var1 = "1,234.567";
var parsed = parseFloat(Var1.replace(",",""), 10);
if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    // its not a valid number, so deal with it as needed
}
else {
    // parsed now holds your Number, so use it
}
```

This approach will work regardless of if the number is >= 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Var1 = "2,356.21";
foundStr = String(Var1.match(/([0-9]{1,3},)?[0-9]{0,3}\.[0-9]+/g)).replace(/,/g, "");
var result = parseFloat(foundStr).toFixed(2);
```